# macOS sierra apple calendar doesn't update to current day

Tags: macos, calendar

The dock icon updates properly but the calendar itself doesn't change the red highlight badge to the current day.

In System Preferences > Date & Time > "Set Date and Time Automatically" is checked.

If I quit the app and relaunch, it does open with the correct day.